# How to properly disable HTTP verbs?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, web-config

We've added the following to our `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <add verb="GET" allowed="true"/>
        <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

When we do an `Invoke-WebRequest` with PowerShell for other verbs than `GET` and `POST` we get the message:

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Does this mean the verb is disabled? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Error 404 could be because of many reasons. However you can verify if your configuration is working or not by setting allowUnlisted="true"> and removing <clear/> tag. Once confirmed then you can revert back to your configuration and recheck.

Comment: Yeah when we did not have the configuration we got a proper response. I was wondering if it is possible to get another more accurate result like `405 Verb not allowed`.

Comment: This is behaviour of IIS in case of request filtering. It throws 404.6. However message for 404.6 is "Verb denied". Checkout this link. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891. You should be good with this error code.

Comment: @PankajKapare Thanks a lot. Strangely enough in the response headers it still says `Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST`. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure however by any chance have you configured CORS support?